# Git. Как полностью заменить содержимое одной ветки другой?

Tags: git

У меня есть ветка `dev` в которой шла разработка, сейчас проект оказался почти польностью переписан в новой ветке `new_arc` которая была создана от `dev`. Теперь мне надо заменить все содержимое `dev` на `new_arc` но если я сделаю `pull` то старые файлы в `dev` остануться, а мне надо чтобы все содержимое `dev` удалилось и сместо него стало содержимое `new_arc`.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, перспектива сделать `pull` и лазать по проекту искать лишние файлы не вдохновляет... Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не нужно нечего из ветки dev, то просто удалите ветку dev и отпочкуйте новую ветку от new_arc.

Comment: ветка dev нужна все фичи в проекте были отпучкованы от нее это конечно сработает но историю dev нельзя терять в ней часть продакшенов старых версий лежит которые даже в master не выводились. В общем надо как то аккуратно так чтобы не повредить ее историю.

Comment: @Pavel, вся ваша история будет в той ветке которую вы когда то отпочковали от dev) Если в dev с момента как отпочковали ветку new_arc  нечего не заливалось, то нечего и не потеряете)

Comment: Ветка в git (в отличии от mercurial) - просто указатель на коммит, от его удаления всё, что вы потеряете - несмердженные коммиты в голове этой ветки, все "отпучкованные" изменения сохранятся как часть других веток.

Answer (score 2):

просто переставьте указатель `dev` на тот коммит, на который указывает указатель `new_arc` («ветка» `dev` не должна быть в этот момет текущей):

```
$ git branch -f dev new_arc
```

---

для сохранения истории коммитов можете перед этим поставить либо метку на тот коммит, на который сейчас указывает указатель `dev`:

```
$ git tag old_dev dev
```

либо указатель:

```
$ git branch old_dev dev
```

---

если где-то (помимо вашего локального компьютера) есть копии того же хранилища, то подобную операцию надо будет проделать во всех остальных копиях.

часто одну из копий (на каком-нибудь сервере) используют совместно. на нём историю придётся перезаписать такой командой:

```
$ git push -f имя-хранилища-обычно-origin dev:dev
```

Comment: Наверное суть вопроса в том, что бы у коллег в ветке dev не произошло слияния старого кода с новым.

Comment: @MaLS, об этом написано в абзаце, начинающемся со слова «если».

Comment: @MaLS, если вы считаете, что подразумевался вопрос: «как перезаписать историю коммитов во всех копиях хранилища, к которым нет прямого доступа?», то ответ на такой вопрос: **никак**.

Comment: А если сначала удалить всё и закоммитить, а затем смержить с new_arc? Эти два коммита не дадут желаемого результата?

Comment: Нужно избежать мержа со старым кодом, а не перезапись истории.

Comment: @MaLS, если под «удалить всё» вы подразумеваете удаление файлов, а не коммитов, а под «содержимым ветки» автор подразумевает содержимое файлов, а не историю коммитов,  то, да, ваше предложение будет ответом на вопрос.